# How do you force gradle to print or log all compiler commands executed?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to see the exact compiler commands (in my case gcc) used by gradle during execution of all build tasks. Running with `--debug` doesn't output these commands, and output files in build/tmp don't have them either. I'm currently using Gradle 2.6

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using the cpp plugin

Comment: is there a build/temp/XX/options.txt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See `$projectDir/build/tmp`

You should have a folder structure that looks something like:

```
├───compileMainSharedLibraryMainCpp
│       options.txt
│       output.txt
│
├───compileMainStaticLibraryMainCpp
│       options.txt
│       output.txt
│
├───createMainStaticLibrary
│       options.txt
│       output.txt
│
└───linkMainSharedLibrary
        options.txt
        output.txt
```

`options.txt` contains the options passed to the compiler/linker etc, and `output.txt` contains the output of the compiler/linker.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for my purposes. I suppose that each folder, then, represents a single invocation of a compiler command, and `options.txt` represents the options given to that command?

Comment: @Bram you should raise a new question referencing this one.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  There must be more to this story:  > gradle clean build; ...lots of output...; find build/tmp -name options.txt -print; ...no output...

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet in *build.gradle* prints options (not complete command line):

```
toolChains {
    gcc(Gcc) {
        eachPlatform { 
            cppCompiler.withArguments { args ->
                println "----> C++ args: " + args
            }
        }
    }
}
```