# How can I see the actual commands (java) running in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, shell, gradle, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA CE in two environments (CentOS and Ubuntu).

The two share a project via GitHub.

In CentOS, the project is regarded as Java project? with a file build.gradle.
In the other, the project is fully managed as Gradle-Java project.

When I run a main method in CentOS, IDE just runs Java (after some compiles if are required)
On the other hand, when I run the same main method in Ubuntu, IDE activates Gradle and run that.

I think this difference happens from the module structures.. which I have not tried though....
(Am I wrong?)

One question I really want to know here is,
in CentOS, when I run a code, it shows how IDE ran the code in the Run window, like...

```
java [too many options] foo.target.Hoge
```

If I copy and paste this line, I can activate foo.target.Hoge anywhere, even where I do not set CLASSPATH because `[too many options]` contain that.

I always do it (I am afraid if I should not though)

However, in Ubuntu (Gradle-based environment)
the windows show only

```
time PM: Executing task 'Hoge.main()'...
```

I can not copy, paste and run it...
I want to know where I can found the actual command activated.
or.... using Gradle..  are there any simpler ways?? like

```
gradle run Java Hoge ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you force gradle to print or log all compiler commands executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248120/how-do-you-force-gradle-to-print-or-log-all-compiler-commands-executed)

Comment: The problem is that gradle does not always invoke a command line action to do things like compilation. Often these things are done manually or through using the provided tooling to programmatically accomplish the same task. _See for example this [guide](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/JavaCompilertoolshowyoucancompileaJavasourcefrominsideaJavaprogram.htm) that shows how to compile java from another java program_

Comment: Thanks but what you taught me is about compilation. I wonder how to invoke classes.  how IDE invokes. (because my project uses many liblaries, so I have to type java -cp hoge.jar:foo.jar:...: Hoge) and my IDEA in CentOS shows that command

Comment: I cannot find one in Run configurations, where I can add other options though....

Comment: Are you not using the [`application`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) plugin?

Comment: I use ( I am not sure I use it correctly though.

Comment: The plugin contains a `run` task which after you use it from intelliJ, should pop up as a Run configuration. You need to specify a `mainClassName` in the `application` extension, then the run task will work

Comment: I mean a case when I right click and Run Hoge.main(), how it is activated.
I do not mean gradle run. (sometime I want to run Foo.main() or Hoge2.main())

Comment: I found one way to see it... >Settings>Build, Execution-> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Nuild and run using -> ( change Gradle----->IntelliJ IDEA) then I can see Java command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run a main method in CentOS, IDE just runs Java (after some compiles if are required) On the other hand, when I run the same main method in Ubuntu, IDE activates Gradle and run that.

For Gradle-based projects this behaviour is controlled in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using** option. When Gradle is set IDE uses [Gradle](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html) to run and build the project. When IntelliJ is set IDE uses it's own [builder](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiler-and-builder.html) and [Run/Debug Configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html) to run.